# file_get_contents catch 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl, file-get-contents

I have a php file that makes a file_get_contents request through proxy servers. Sometimes, I get a 403 forbidden error response because of the proxy, and in stead of retrying the same request with a different proxy, it just skips to the next request so the data is lost.

I know that with curl there is a way to catch the error and if its a 403 forbidden, retry with another proxy but I can't find anywhere if this is possible with file_get_contents.

Thanks a lot for taking your time to read my problem and I would really appreciate your help,
Sincerely,

Comment: You can use file_get_contents with stream_context_create() to put more options (headers and others). And you can check the response status with $http_response_header. Antoher idea is to use guzzle.

Comment: Thanks! $http_response_header[0] is what I was looking for.

Comment: Now the problem that I have is that the code I developed gets into an infinite loop and I dont know why. What I coded was:

while ($http_response_header[0] = "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden") {
$filejson = file_get_contents('$url, False, $cxContext);
}

I dont understand why it gets into this loop as $cxContext is a rotating proxy that should change the ip with every request and therefore change the response header from 403 to 200, right?

Comment: You need to use `==` in your `while (...)` statement, not `=`. That should clear up your infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I don't get the infinite loop but when the http request gets a 403 code it just continues with the code in stead of trying again with another request to the proxy.
I would appreciate also if you could explain why in this situation == would be more appropiate than =

Thanks a lot for your time ;)

Comment: Can you update your first post to show us the code ?